# Calculate round(avg) from same table and join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables,

users

```
userid   fname    usertype
1        Steve    vendor
2        Peter    vendor
3        John     normaluser
4        Mark     normaluser
5        Kevin    vendor
6        Alan     vendor
7        Sean     vendor
```

vendor_rating

```
id   userid   rating
1    1        4
2    2        3
3    2        2
4    2        4
5    1        3
6    5        2
7    5        2
```

userid is foreign key.

i want to show all vendors (only usertype vendor) from user table by descending/ascending average rating even if Vendor's rating is not available on table it should show, its information should display at last in descending, at first in ascending.

I want to fetch all users info from first table so i m using left join :

```
  SELECT
  users.name,
  users.userid,
  users.usertype
FROM users
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
      ROUND(AVG(rating)) AS rating_avg,
      userid
    FROM vendor_rating
    ORDER BY rating_avg DESC) ven
    ON users.usertype = 'vendor'
    AND users.userid = ven.userid
ORDER BY ven.rating_avg ASC;
```

Please help where am i going wrong.

EDIT:

I get this

```
userid  ROUND(AVG(vr.ratings))

28          5
27          4
16          3
26          2
25          0
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
```

if i use

```
 SELECT vr.userid, ROUND(AVG(vr.ratings)) FROM vendor_rating vr
 RIGHT JOIN (SELECT users.fname, users.userid, users.usertype FROM users) u 
ON u.id = vr.vendor_id WHERE u.usertype = 'vendor' GROUP BY vr.userid,u.fname 
ORDER BY round(avg(vr.ratings)) ASC
```

i get NULL values from users table whose rating is not available in vendor_rating table those should display userids

Comment: You haven't actually defined what isn't working.  Is the problem that you're getting output for users 3 and 4, but you don't want that?  *(Move the  `users.usertype='vendor'` in to a WHERE clause.)*

Comment: add your desired resultset in your question

Comment: @MatBailie my query return all user including vendor and normaluser and even it is not sorting by avg rating with asc/desc result

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid its returning null average rating for those who has ratings

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid how about this SELECT vr.userid, ROUND(AVG(vr.ratings)) FROM vendor_rating vr RIGHT JOIN (SELECT users.fname, users.userid, users.usertype FROM users) u ON u.id = vr.vendor_id WHERE u.usertype = 'vendor' GROUP BY vr.userid,u.fname ORDER BY round(avg(vr.ratings)) ASC BUT THIS RETURNS NULL VALUES WHOSE DATA IS NOT AVLBLE IN VENDOR_RATING TABLE

Comment: As a side note, if you have an outer query with an `ORDER BY`, subqueries with different ones (and nothing like a `LIMIT` clause) have no effect (and may be discarded by the optimizer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got it

```
SELECT users.fname, users.userid,users.usertype
FROM users  
LEFT JOIN (select ROUND(AVG (ratings)) AS rating_avg,userid FROM 
vendor_rating group by userid order by rating_avg desc ) ven 
ON users.id=userid 
WHERE users.usertype='vendor'
order by rating_avg desc
```

Thank you all, for sharing views to get idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to this**

```
SELECT
  vr.userid,
  u.fname,
  ROUND(AVG(vr.rating))
FROM vendor_rating vr
  INNER JOIN users u
    ON u.userid = vr.userid
WHERE u.usertype = 'vendor'
GROUP BY vr.userid,
         u.fname
ORDER BY round(avg(vr.rating)) ASC
```

Comment: how can i sort it by ascending/descending of avg rating

Comment: can you try order by  round(avg(vr.rating)) ASC or DESC end of the query

Comment: thanks for sharing answer, but what i want to show also all those vendors from users table whose data is not available in vendor_rating

Comment: you can use "having round(avg(vr.rating)) = 0" after group by

Comment: it only return one result whose rating is zero, i think there is need for left join to select all results from users table whose usertype is vendor

Comment: of course you can change sql command according to your needs. If you want to show also all elements whether match you should use left join.

Comment: But if you use left join for this need you should decide which table should be right or left. Because you must change sql according to this conditions

Comment: how about this        SELECT
  vr.userid,
  ROUND(AVG(vr.ratings))
FROM vendor_rating vr
  RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT
  users.fname,
  users.userid,
  users.usertype
FROM users) u
    ON u.id = vr.vendor_id
WHERE u.usertype = 'vendor'
GROUP BY vr.userid,u.fname
ORDER BY round(avg(vr.ratings)) ASC       BUT THIS RETURNS NULL VALUES WHOSE DATA IS NOT AVLBLE IN VENDOR_RATING TABLE